# R plot function code as caption

Tags: r, string, function, plot

How can I convert a function to a string?

To be more clear: I do have a function that gets a quantile function then prepares some data to plot. I would like to include the quantile function in the plots caption.

```
myfunction = function(qfunc = function(p) qnorm(p)) {
  # do something
  plot(data, sub = qfunc)
}
```

I would like the plot to have `function(p) qnorm(p)` or whatever has been passed as qfunc as a subcaption.
How do I do this?

Comment: `deparse(substitute(qfunc)))` should do the trick

Comment: This solves my problem. `deparse` does the trick :-) Thank you.